# 404 error when performing "Get" request to API

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Trying to perform a "get" request to API.  I know the API will return the data when I do the "get" from Postman. So I believe the problem is with my HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <h1>My First Heading</h1>
    <p>My first paragraph.</p>

        <script>
            const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
            const url='https://localhost:44369';
            Http.open("GET", url);
            Http.send();

            Http.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
            console.log(Http.responseText)
            }

        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Here's the API method I'm trying to "get" from:**

```
    //https://localhost:44369/api/Request
    [EnableCors("AllowLocalhostOrigins")]
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetText()
    {
       string a = "b";

        return Ok(a);
    }
```

**Here's the error I'm getting:**
[404 Not Found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsOzn.png)

Comment: Well, you say your API method is at `https://localhost:44369/api/Request` but in your JS code you are trying to request from `https://localhost:44369`.

Comment: Yes, when I use https://localhost:44369/api/Request in the HTML, I get two errors instead of one.  I get an "Access blocked by CORs policy" and a "200 Err_Failed."  When I use https://localhost:44369 in the HTML I get one error and that is the 404.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some more reading, I see that it's a problem with the API and not the html code I posted this question about.  The html code I posted works fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).